# Blocking particular apps in Android (By modifying source code)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-source, android-framework

The projcet involves modifying Android to block/deny launching of particular apps. So if user tries to launch any of the pre-listed apps by any means, that app shouldn't get launched.

I'll be modifying Android source code. What are the different ways to do it?  Suggestions are welcome.

I think one of the possible ways to do that is to modify `Process.java` in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/os`.
This class has `start` function which receives `uid` as an input paramenter. I think from this parameter we can get to know that for which app new process is being created. Is this the correct way to do it?

Also, as the apps are launched using intents, is it possible (by modifying any class) to remove particular intents?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to prevent the installing of these black-listed apps?

Comment: The blocking has to be done only for particular period (say, from 9am to 5pm). Other than this interval, user can use that app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when an intent can be handled by an application(its activity, service), and the user prefers that application to handle it. The `ActivityManagerService(Ams)` in Android framework will first see whether the corresponding application of the target activity/service is still alive. If it hasn't been started yet or killed, the Ams will start that application by calling `startProcessLocked` method.

```
final ProcessRecord startProcessLocked(String processName,
            ApplicationInfo info, boolean knownToBeDead, int intentFlags,
            String hostingType, ComponentName hostingName, boolean allowWhileBooting,
            boolean isolated) {
    //you can get the uid from ApplicationInfo.uid
    ...
    startProcessLocked(app, hostingType, hostingNameStr);
    ...
}

private final void startProcessLocked(ProcessRecord app,
            String hostingType, String hostingNameStr) {
    //prepare its uid, gid, gids for starting that process
    ...
    Process.ProcessStartResult startResult = Process.start("android.app.ActivityThread",
                    app.processName, uid, uid, gids, debugFlags, mountExternal,
                    app.info.targetSdkVersion, null, null);
    ...
}
```

So in that method, it start a new process. The `Process.start` is what you have mentioned in your question, and it finally calls Zygote to fork a new process.

I think intercepting the application startup process in Ams is a better way. You can get more information about this application and it is also the upstream of your `Process.start` method.

UPDATE:

Just noticed that you were thinking about restricting intent. An intent can be handled by multiple applications, so we cannot restrict applications from sending a particular intent. But we can modify the resolving process. `Resolving` means the Android framework need to determine which activity/service can handle this intent. If there are multiple choices and the user haven't set any preference, then the following dialog will appear:

[image: Intent Handling]

So it is possible to modify the resolving process to let the Android framework discard the fact that your specific application is able to handle that intent. I think this is also a way to do your work but it is much more compilicated because Android resolves intent differently for activity, service and receiver. For activity, Ams will call `resolveIntent` in `PackageManagerService` to get which activity to start. For service, it is the `resolveService` method in `PackageManagerService` get called. So you need to handle them differently. But since they will all get a list of ResolveInfo in their implementation, you can just filter out your application easily. For example, in `resolveIntent` in `PackageManagerService`:

```
@Override
public ResolveInfo resolveIntent(Intent intent, String resolvedType,
        int flags, int userId) {
    if (!sUserManager.exists(userId)) return null;
    enforceCrossUserPermission(Binder.getCallingUid(), userId, false, "resolve intent");
    List<ResolveInfo> query = queryIntentActivities(intent, resolvedType, flags, userId);
    //filter out here!!!!
    return chooseBestActivity(intent, resolvedType, flags, query, userId);
}
```

You can easily get the ApplicationInfo from the ResolveInfo if you take a look at `ResolveInfo.java`.

For receiver, it is even more complicated because receivers registered in AndroidManifest.xml and by `registerReceiver(...)` are different. If the intent in broadcastIntent hasn't set the flag FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY(common case), then the resolving result would be a list of receivers that listen to that broadcast, which may contain two kinds of receivers. For those in AndroidManifest.xml, Ams will call `queryIntentReceiver` in `PackageManagerService` to get a list of receivers that listen to a broadcast. For those registered dynamically by `registerReciever(...)`,  they are managed by `ActivityManagerService` not `PackageManagerService`, so Ams will directly call `mReceiverResolver.queryIntent` to get those receivers. The `mReceiverResolver` is defined as:

```
final IntentResolver<BroadcastFilter, BroadcastFilter> mReceiverResolver
        = new IntentResolver<BroadcastFilter, BroadcastFilter>() {
        ...
}
```

So what you need to do is override the queryIntent method to filter out the receivers in your application. For ContentProvider, the method is `resolveContentProvider` in `PackageManagerService`. Same way to handle it.

Comment: wow, quite nice explanation!!! Thank you. After reading this, I think it is easier to modify `Process` related functions in Ams rather than overriding intent related functions.

Comment: @user1010 - Were you able to block particular apps? I need to do this same.